# How to adjust size of symbols in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, size

In text mode the size of text can be adjusted easily. In the code below the second string is much bigger than the first one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

test \\
\Huge{test}

\end{document}
```

However trying the same does not work in math mode. In this code the second division symbol is not enlarged.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\div$ \\
$\Huge{\div}$

\end{document}
```

How can I change the size of symbols in math mode?

Comment: just move `\Huge` before the `$` (and remove the `{}`)

Comment: note `\Huge{test}` is wrong, it makes the rest of the document huge, not just `test`

Comment: This looks like an XY-problem. What’s the application you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Choose the size before starting the math.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

test

{\Huge test}

$\div$

{\Huge$\div$}

test

\end{document}
```

Comment: `{\Huge$\div$\par}`? Otherwise all the interline skips are wrong.

Comment: @HenriMenke possibly but unlikely to want an entire paragraph with one symbol, so perhaps the OP wants a big symbol in  a normal para and live with opening up the lines